# Select XML element based on the value of a tag

Tags: xml, command-line, kml, xmlstarlet

I need to select all `<Style>` blocks from a KML that contain the color `ccff00ff`. Something like:

```
<Style id="inline">
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ccff00ff</color>
        <width>5</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
```

I have been beating my head against the wall for hours, and this is the *closest* I could get based on [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/discussion/226076/thread/a0827031):

```
xmlstarlet sel -N 'ns=http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' -t -c '//ns:Style[.//ns:color[contains(text(), 'ccff00ff')]]' myplaces.kml
```

Unfortunately, if I change `ccff00ff` to whatever I want, it still matches, so I can assume it doesn't work at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'//ns:Style[.//ns:color[contains(text(), 'ccff00ff')]]'
```

Quotes don't nest; use double quotes inside the single ones:

```
'//ns:Style[.//ns:color[contains(text(), "ccff00ff")]]'
```

The example you linked had the quotes the other way around, because `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize single quotes as quoting characters. Since bash does recognize double quotes as quoting characters too you could do it that way, but they are "soft quotes" so you could run into some trouble with that. As far as XPath is concerned, both quote types are completely identical.

Comment: OMG, that was so simple, I feel embarrassed! I'm actually on bash on Linux, but that did the trick. I must have been half asleep or something...

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: sometimes you just need a set of fresh eyes. Syntax highlighting can also help.

Comment: Ah, yes sure. I was working directly on the terminal, though. Thank you!